# List number alignment using CSS3

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create the following effect using CSS3 (targeting Chrome only). Essentially I want a numbered `<ol>` element which contains one radio button and one label. The aim is to get the list number, the radio & the label to all align in the center:

[image: Crude Drawing]

This is my markup:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="left">
                <input type="radio" />
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <label>Some really long text here that overlaps a few lines. Some really long text here that overlaps a few lines. Some really long text here that overlaps a few lines. Some really long text here that overlaps a few lines</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

And the CSS I have so far:

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex
}
.left {
    width: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
.right {
    flex: 1;
}
input {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
```

And a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8LDq/) of the above.

I've tried using floats (which breaks the `<ol>` numbering), I've tried using wrapping divs and different display types (`table`/`table-cell`) and I've landed at my closest effort yet by using `flex`.

The problem is I still can't get the list number to line up with the radio buttons. It always aligns to the top of the `<li>` (along with some random whitespace which I can't figure out).

I'm open to using *anything* to create the desired effect shown in the image. Even Javascript/jQuery. But only if a pure CSS option is not possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you really need all those `div's` inside your `li`? if not, it's all a matter of `vertical-align` and setting the `width` of the elements inside.

You could rewrite your html to:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" />
        <label>Some really long text here that overlaps a few lines. Some really long text here that overlaps a few lines. Some really long text here that overlaps a few lines. Some really long text here that overlaps a few lines</label>
    </li>
</ol>
```

and css to:

```
li input {
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    display:inline-block;
    width:5%;
}
li label {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:inline-block;
    width:90%;
}
```

Here is a demo **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mjeG/1/)**

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! The extra `<div>` were a result of me (blindly) adding elements in order to resolve the issue. Turns out I was just making work for myself...

Comment: It happens to all of us :) Glad I could help

Answer (score 4):

You can recreate the numbers as stylable elements and then align them wherever you want

```
ol {
    counter-reset:li;
    margin-left:0;
    padding-left:0;
}

ol > li {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 0 6px 2em;
    padding:4px 8px;
    list-style:none;
}
ol > li:before {
    content:counter(li);
    counter-increment:li;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left : -2em;
    width:2em;
    height: 4em;
    margin: -14px 8px 0 0; /* same as font-size */
    padding: 4px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/y8LDq/13/)

This would work regardless of the content inside the LI's